# Slot in array based on value in php

Tags: php, arrays

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 1
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 100
                    [3] => -10
                    [2] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 2
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 0
                    [3] => -5
                    [2] => -50
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 3
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 50
                    [3] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [agent_id] => 4
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 50
                    [3] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 1
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 3
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 4
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 2
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1

        )
}
```

Above have 2 arrays, how can I break the array 1 which is the **'details'** and store into array 2 based on their **agent_id**? I tried to loop array1 and match with **agent_id** but failed to do that. Anyone can help with this :(? The Final end result will be only 1 array does it mean that the array1 **'details'** that will store into array2.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
   if($array1['agent_id'] == $finalResult[$key]['agent_Id']){
        $array2['detais'] = $value['details'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to insert the `details` from `$array1` into the entry in `$array2` which has the same `agent_id` value. To do that, you can iterate over `$array1`, using [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on the `agent_Id` column of `$array2` to find the appropriate entry, and then copy the details to that:

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    $key = array_search($value['agent_id'], array_column($array2, 'agent_Id'));
    if ($key !== false) {
        $array2[$key]['details'] = $value['details'];
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 1
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 100
                    [3] => -10
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 3
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 50
                    [3] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 4
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 50
                    [3] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [agent_Id] => 2
            [total] => 90
            [room_Id] => 1
            [user_Id] => 1
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 0
                    [3] => -5
                    [2] => -50
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aVhih)